# Date and time control in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added the JQuery mobile date box in ASP.NET MVC 4 but It won't work in iPhone. I've tried the instructions on this link:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/flip/

Please help me to add date and time picker in JQuery mobile.

Comment: No i didn't get any error.When i cilck on the select button it does not close popup.

Comment: please give example link/code?

Comment: this is the link I have use http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Answer (score 0):

Date & Time Picker with jQuery Mobile Theme integration. Take a look at this [post](http://blog.mobiscroll.com/jquery-mobile-theme-integration/).